# python not accessible in powershell v3 when opened with Popen

Tags: python-2.7, powershell-3.0, cinema-4d

Hopefully this should be simple. Python environment is running fine if I open PowerShell v3 manually. I can check version and run external scripts etc. But as soon as I open powershell.exe through subprocess.Popen from a python script from another application, python simply won't run; "The term 'Python' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program... etc"

I've checked my environment paths repeatedly and python is running fine on the system in general.

anyone has any idea what this could be caused by?

```
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'RemoteSigned', "path to PS1_script_with python command"])
```

My PS1 file looks like this:

```
cd C:\Users\David\Geeknote\geeknote-master\geeknote
python gnsync.py --path "C:\Users\David\Desktop\C4DtoEvernote", --mask "*.nfo", --notebook "Python Logs" 
function Pause{Read-Host 'You have successfully synced your C4D Annotations to Evernote using gnsync.
Please press Enter to continue...' | Out-Null}
Pause{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (for whatever reason) your `$PATH` is not being read or honored by the process; and thus `python` cannot be found.

You can either:

1. Set up the path with `$env:Path = "C:\Python27:C:\Python27\Scripts";`
2. Setup the path using a custom console profile (ie, a `.ps1` file) and passing it with [`-PSConsoleFile`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx).
3. The simplest option, pass the full path to the Python executable in your command file `C:\Python27\python.exe gsync.py ...`

I would try #3, and then see if you need the other options.

Adjust the paths as appropriate - especially if you have multiple Python interpreters installed.

Comment: thanks yes #3 works ;) feeling a bit dim I didn't think of that but I was obviously banging my head against the wall. Regarding #1 is the syntax completely correct there or should there be a semicolon there? I did try it but it seemed to have deleted some path commands I had there before. It didn't solve the issue tho. #2 Im not sure how to implement yet.